# windows phone 8 share content via Email,Facebook,and Twitter

Tags: c#, facebook, email, twitter, windows-phone-8

i am developing a windows phone 8 application where i want to share all the data in that page via email, face-book and Twitter. In that page i have some image and description and also some other links, i want to share all the information via Email, Face-book and Twitter. i came to know that i can achieve these tasks via ShareLinkTask();. but my problem is via this Sharelink Task i can send Title LinkUri and Message only.  i am not able to  send the image from shareLinkTask is there any option to share the image.

is there any possibility to prepare a html string from the data i have and make it as a **link uri** then i can share the complete information via that LinkUri.

and one more doubt is ShareLinkTask is a good option to share information to facebook and Twitter.

suggest me a better solution to share the page content along with images via Email,FaceBook and Twitter in Windows phone 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing doesn't work like you described. You can't just share contents of a page. You can either share a link through `ShareLinkTask` or share an image through `ShareMediaTask`.

You could however upload the contents of your page to your site then share a link to it.

**edit:**

Yes you can take a screen shot of your page, save it then share it as an image.

```cs
// This copies your whole page as in image to a writable bitmap
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, new TranslateTransform());
```

Note you need to save your image in media library before you can share it using `ShareMediaTask` as you cannot specify a file located in isolated storage.

Comment: in that case can i take a screen shot of my page and share it via ShareMediatask. sharemediatask will work for email , facebook and twitter if so can you post some sample code or links